# I can't get my icon to show up in my JLabel swing component

Tags: java, swing

Below is the java Swing code to place a icon in a JLabel Swing component.

```
package com.TheMcLeodgrp;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame {
  public Main() throws HeadlessException {
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("myIcon.gif");
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Full Name :", icon, JLabel.LEFT);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Address :", JLabel.LEFT);
    label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("myIcon.gif"));

    getContentPane().add(label1);
    getContentPane().add(label2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

It is a simple label program where everything else works fine.  The icon **(myIcon.gif)** just wont show up in the label when I run the program. I am running it from a standard Eclipse IDE, and **myIcon.gif** resides in a folder - ie; **images/myIcon.gif.** It seems like I missing something simple here, but I don't know.  Do I need to place the icon somewhere else in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following article will do much better job of explaining how to load image resources then I will :)

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll second @eugener's recommendation on the tutorial. Also, try using the relative path, and check the result of constructing the `ImageIcon`:

```
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Address :", JLabel.LEFT);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/myIcon.gif");
if (icon.getIconWidth() == -1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "No image!", "Gahh!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else {
    label2.setIcon(icon);
}
```